Updating user in supabase updates and ovefrride all fields or just applied fields?
assuming my data of user looks like this:
interface SignUpObject {
  email:string,
  password: string,
  options: {
    emailRedirectTo: string,
    captchaToken?: string,
    data: {
      preferedLanguage: number
      name: string
      email: string
      agreeTermsCheckbox: boolean
      whatJobYouHave: number
      birthday: string
      subscriber_expiration_timestamp: string | null
    }
  }
}

if i update user options with only one param, lets say the "name" field, does it override everything?
here's an update example
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.updateUser({
  options: {
    name: 'test new name'
  }
})

